# Best way to save dynamic web page configuration data in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

We have a highly configurable asp.net web application. Different groups (100+ groups) can log in to the application. For each group we have a configurable xml file with information as to how to display the page. When user logs in, based on their group id and the configuration settings in the xml file, the web page is displayed.

For instance:
Group1.xml

```
<Group1>
 <item key="Shape" value="True" />
 <item key="Color" value="False" />
 <item key="Submit" value="False" />
<Group1>
```

Group2.xml

```
<Group2>
 <item key="Shape" value="True" />
 <item key="Color" value="True" />
 <item key="Submit" value="True" />
<Group2>
```

In the above example, Shape and Color are text boxes and Submit is a button. Based on the values (True or False) we either display the text box or hide the text box thus dynamically rendering the web page.

Saving this type data in the xml file in app_data folder has worked really well so far. But as we add more groups and more elements on each page, managing each xml file to ensure every xml file has same elements and correct values is getting difficult (there are thousands of elements and 50+ web pages).

We tried saving this data in a table in the database. But making so many database calls to read values one at a time is expensive and performance of the page decreases.

We tried saving this data in a table and save the table in a data table session variable at page load. But these configuration settings can be altered by other groups. Since the changes made by other groups wont be loaded to the session for the current user until they refresh the page, we have undesirable results.

We also tried to use an excel file in app_data folder and use it as a table to read values one at a time so even if other groups change a value, we always get the latest value to render the page. Not sure if this is a correct or elegant solution.

What is the best way to store this type of configuration information such that even with lots of reads and writes the performance of the page does not decrease and at the same time easy enough to manage all these configuration settings across all groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I would advocate a database driven solution, however, it sounds as though you already have a system that works well for you and is proven, so don't throw that away just yet. If I read your question correctly, your current xml driven settings work well and the solution scales ok.

Your issue is not so much with the run-time performance or accuracy, so don't change this.

Rather, it is with how you manage those xml files. A couple of quick questions:

Is it one application with 50 or so pages rather than lots of applications?
Does every group have similar settings, just different values?

If the answer to both of those questions is yes, then you should try [ConfigGen](https://configgen.codeplex.com/) .
It was developed for generating machine-specific app.config and web.config files, but it could be easily used to generate any settings file.

The way it works is that you have one tokenised xml template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<group name="[%groupName%]">
   <item key="Shape" value="[%shape%]" />
   <item key="Color" value="[%color%]" />
   <item key="Submit" value="[%submit%]" />
</group>
```

You also have a spreadsheet or csv file that contains a line for each of your groups and a column for each setting. The group settings go into this spreadsheet and the column names match the tokens in the template file.

```
MachineName    ConfigFilePath    groupName    shape    color    submit
Default        default.xml       defaultgroup True     True     True
Group1         Group1.xml        Group1       True     False    False 
Group2         Group2.xml        Group2       True     True     True
```

At build time (not runtime) configGen uses the two files to generate an output config for each group.

This makes managing the settings for each group really simple, and you won't have to change a single line of your application code. It is really easy in excel to look down through a column and check your settings in one place. I personally prefer to use a csv file because it merges better in source control systems.

I hope this helps.

On the other hand, if you are having performance issues, and it sounds as though you did with your database driven solutions, then you might need to make some changes in your app. Regardless of how your settings are stored, they should only be retrieved from the DB or the file system once, preferably at application start up. The settings should be read into a hash table or dictionary keyed on your group name and cached for the duration. If it needs to be dynamic, then you would have to provide some management page for either invalidating the whole lot, or preferably just the settings affected.

Read up on Read-Through caching.